# Can't request keyboard IRQ 1 on the Raspberry Pi in linux driver

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3

Here is some part of my driver source code:

```
#define KEYBOARD_IRQ        1

err = request_irq(KEYBOARD_IRQ, (irq_handler_t) st7735_keyboard_interrupt, 
                  IRQF_SHARED, "st7735_keyboard_interrupt", 
                  (void *)(st7735_keyboard_interrupt));
if(err) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "ST7735 : ERROR : Failed to request keyboard interrupt\n");
        return err;
}
```

The return value is -22 - EINVAL. I suspect the issue is in the keyboard IRQ number. The keyboard is connected to RPi.

cat /proc/bus/input/devices:

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1c4f Product=0026 Version=0110
N: Name="SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:1C4F:0026.0001/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=10000 7 ff800000 7ff febeffdf f3cfffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1c4f Product=0026 Version=0110
N: Name="SIGMACHIP USB Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:1C4F:0026.0002/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=3007f 0 0 0 0 483ffff 17aff32d bf544446 0 0 1 130c13 b17c000 267bfa d941dfed 9e1680 4400 0 10000002
B: REL=40
B: ABS=1 0
B: MSC=10
```

cat /proc/interrupts:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
 16:          0          0          0          0  bcm2836-timer   0 Edge      arch_timer
 17:      11098      13199      12423       3164  bcm2836-timer   1 Edge      arch_timer
 21:          0          0          0          0  bcm2836-pmu   9 Edge      arm-pmu
 23:        929          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level   1 Edge      3f00b880.mailbox
 24:          2          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level   2 Edge      VCHIQ doorbell
 46:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  48 Edge      bcm2708_fb dma
 48:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  50 Edge      DMA IRQ
 50:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  52 Edge      DMA IRQ
 51:        355          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  53 Edge      DMA IRQ
 54:       1995          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  56 Edge      DMA IRQ
 55:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  57 Edge      DMA IRQ
 56:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  58 Edge      DMA IRQ
 59:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  61 Edge      bcm2835-auxirq
 62:    1348363          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  64 Edge      dwc_otg, dwc_otg_pcd, dwc_otg_hcd:usb1
 83:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  85 Edge      3f804000.i2c
 84:     102410          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  86 Edge      3f204000.spi
 86:        285          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  88 Edge      mmc0
 87:       4819          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  89 Edge      uart-pl011
 92:      30543          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  94 Edge      mmc1
FIQ:              usb_fiq
IPI0:          0          0          0          0  CPU wakeup interrupts
IPI1:          0          0          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI2:       3946      26730      81970      29799  Rescheduling interrupts
IPI3:         17          4          7          7  Function call interrupts
IPI4:          0          0          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
IPI5:       1854       1806       5681        314  IRQ work interrupts
IPI6:          0          0          0          0  completion interrupts
```

Help me please to understand how I should to request keyboard IRQ in my system.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?   The ST7735 is a little TFT controller, are you trying to pass some hardware buttons on a display module off as a keyboard?  If so how are they connected - if they have distinct pins, can you use GPIO interrupts, maybe even in userspace?   If you have to poll them over SPI or I2C then you probably wouldn't use an interrupt at all.

Comment: Can you debug  by using `dumpstack()` or by placing prints why exactly does `request_irq` return the error, there appears to be multiple causes of for this to fail with -22

Comment: You do a common mistake here, i.e. *request_irq()* takes **Linux** IRQ number when you supply **hardware** one.

Comment: @yashC, no need to debug to understand that there is no record in RB-tree with key 1. See my comment above.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes this is TFT controller but it's nothing to do with it. I want to catch some keyboard signals (keys) and display them on the TFT. I am a little concerned that many here do not answer my question, but are distracted by a separate line of code. This way you don't earn much rating and don't help anybode.

Comment: @0andriy, thanks)) you are so persistent)

Comment: The answer you accepted doesn't solve your problem, it just explains why you can't do this *irrelevant* thing with an IRQ that you were trying to. My "distraction" was to focus on how you could solve your actual goal.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I accepted answer from Sanchayan Maity because he indicated to me that my solution to the problem was wrong. As I understand it, the IRQ1 is a keyboard interrupt only on x86 processors. We need to write correct usb keyboard driver for RPi's BCM2835 because there is not fixed IRQ number for keyboard here. You just did not understand what I needed and started writing about things that are as far as possible from solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define IRQ numbers of your own choosing just like that. IRQ1 probably is a very low level core system interrupt. This seems a USB keyboard which should ideally work out of the box or this some custom chip?. Please have a look at how to write drivers which interface over USB. For example, see [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c). See [Chapter13](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/).

Comment: What you are talking about? See my comments to the question.

Comment: I am talking about two things. 1. The IRQ number for request_irq should have come from a call to platform_get_irq which returns Linux IRQ numbers, while it has been specified as 1 by OP which will be probably a core system interrupt. Also [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/IRQ-domain.txt). 2. Based on the output shared I assume a USB device, hence I talked about USB, however from other comments seems it is a TFT controller.?

Comment: @SanchayanMaity yes this is TFT controller but it's nothing to do with it. I want to catch some keyboard signals (keys) and display them on the TFT. Thanks for the response.